# Move javascript files into inline html

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application that allows the use of inline javascript, but not javascript from source files. I'm trying to modify a webpage to open on this browser, and need to know how to put the javascript files from the webpage inline.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<script>` tags in your HTML. They can go anywhere - I prefer inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          // put anything here - any type of valid javascript works
          // if you import jquery, you can use jquery here too!
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place your imported code into the `script` tag in your HTML page (application in your case), look at the following example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                  //Import your JS script here, e.g.:
                  function doSomething(){
                   ..
                  }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>...</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd put `<script>` in the end of body to optimize user experience

Comment: @myroman how would that optimize the script? I'd load it beneath the `HTML` so it won't give an error when trying manipulate the `DOM`.

Comment: the most optimized place that I familiar with is beneath the closing tag of the body

Comment: Talking about user experience, when browser processes the page and finds a script element, it stops rendering and executes it, so the page rendering suspends for some amount of time depending on what the script does. So user would see a blank screen for some time if the page contains a long-running script in the `<head>`. So putting in the end of body is always better unless you have specific requirements for scripts (e.g. some statistic-collecting scripts like SiteCatalyst are put in the head)